# Filling holes in image with OpenCV or Skimage

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I m trying to fill holes for a chessboard for stereo application. The chessboard is at micro scale thus it is complicated to avoid dust... as you can see :

[image]

Thus, the corners detection is impossible. I tried with SciPy's binary_fill_holes or similar approaches but i have a full black image, i dont understand.

Comment: Try to use an opening

Comment: Or invert the image, use find contours, fill them black and invert back again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function that replaces the color of each pixel with the color that majority of its neighbor pixels have.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def remove_noise(gray, num):
    Y, X = gray.shape
    nearest_neigbours = [[
        np.argmax(
            np.bincount(
                gray[max(i - num, 0):min(i + num, Y), max(j - num, 0):min(j + num, X)].ravel()))
        for j in range(X)] for i in range(Y)]
    result = np.array(nearest_neigbours, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.imwrite('result2.jpg', result)
    return result
```

Demo:

```
img = cv2.imread('mCOFl.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

remove_noise(gray, 10)
```

Input image:

[image]

Out put:

[image]

Note: Since this function replace the color of corner pixels too, you can sue `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` function to find the corners and restrict the denoising for that pixels

```
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 30)
corners = np.squeeze(np.int0(corners))
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting results! :) It works well but the drawback is the diffusion at the corners conducting to an increase of errors i think. Perhaps i could erode after your correction?

Comment: I thought to a median filter but it conducts to the same problem.

Comment: @user3601754 Yes I was about to add an explanation regarding that. I think There is a way for refusing that by finding the corners and escaping the operation on them.

Comment: Yep i cant detect the corners with "cv2.findChessboardCorners" function :(

Comment: Ismt this nearly the same  like just eroding the image?

Comment: @PSchn Yeah, kind of.

Comment: So why not using opening instead?! The "holes" would be filled and the shape intact. Or use the method i mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use morphology: dilate, and then erode with same kernel size.

Answer (score 0):

A faster, more accurate way is to use `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects` [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects)

```
im = imread('a.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = im ==255
from skimage import morphology
cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(im, 200)
```

[image]